# How to generate random number within kernel of FreeBSD at root level?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, freebsd

For my Operating System course, I implementing lottery scheduling algorithm instead of what was already given for FreeBSD.

In order to implement lottery scheduling, I have to be able to use random number. However, I can't use C standard library (that uses rand function) within kernel of FreeBSD. `

I am modifying two `.c` file from root (`sched_ule.c` and `kern_switch.c`) that's in `/sys/kern` and trying to make random variable within `sched_ule.c` file using `random.h` that is in `/sys/sys`

As of now, I'm hoping to make small step and get random number to be printed out after running `make buildkernel` and rebooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implement your own Pseudo RNG. C Rand does not generate secure randomness, so you could do the same.
2. If you are on post-ivybridge intel-x86, you could just execute rdrand (which is a hack, but would work fine). I suspect other archs have a similar instruction or mechanism.
3. Use FreeBSD's randomness functions. It almost certainly has a randomness extractor implementation.